# What does git -H do?

Tags: linux, git

I am working with this command: `sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:backup:create RAILS_ENV=production`
and I am the root user so I should be able to also use the command without sudo but Linux says to me after I used the command without sudo that -H is a unknown option.

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk: I don't know what makes you think that; looking at the man page I found, `-h` means "help" and `-H` means "set HOME according to the specified user"... very different!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not `git -H`, it's an option to `sudo`. Read this as:

```
sudo         // This is what we're running
-u git       // Run the command specified later as user "git"
-H bundle    // Set the HOME environment variable to that of user "bundle"
exec rake gitlab:backup:create // The command to execute
```

If `sudo` is complaining that it doesn't know what `-H` means, that may mean you have an old version of `sudo` that doesn't support it, or that your flavour of `sudo` uses a different command line option for the same behaviour. I'd suggest checking for updates, and then using `man sudo` to check for the exact version you're running locally and which options it accepts.